# Will an express card|34 to PCIe x16 work?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, pci-express, expresscard

My laptop has an ExpressCard|54 (it will fit ExpressCard|34 as well) and I want to add a discrete GPU, the AMD Radeon RX 580 8GB. Will the ExpressCard|34 to PCIe x16 adaptor work?

Comment: They are two variations of the 54 mm slot.  Which one does your device support?

Answer (score -1):

For GPUs you have to remember: Your adapter needs 12V power in (for the PCIE slot power) and the GPU needs full 12V (PCIe-power plug). Also the GND (ground) needs to be connected together.

Than, it should work. PCIe is a very, very compatible interface. It can however be a problem, if the Slot is not directly connected to the CPU. Chipsets can result in some incompatibility with some advanced PCIe devices. There is no gurantee and you also need the correct drivers in the OS. Maybe there are also some Bios settings related to PCIe, that can change the results.

You definitely have to try out, there is no gurantee. Let us know however, because it realy is interesting.

Edit: Also remember: If you have an adapter with 1/2/4 lanes, the PCIe card cannot run in x16 lane mode. Also, this can be limiting, if you have a combination of low lanes count and low PCIe revision. Like PCIe gen1 x1 will be limiting a GPU a lot, but nontheless should almost all the time still work just fine (of course with a *lot* of bottleneck). Test for yourself.